# Baby monitor interfering with wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router

This wifi Issue has been making me tear my hair out for months. We have 50/20 internet here at home. And a baby monitor.

Trouble is the baby monitor interferes with the stock router's wifi at 2.4GHz, so I installed a dual band router (a cheap Netgear). When I switched off the 2.4GHz mode on the router.  5GHz works great when you're close to the router, but the range here in our old house is terrible — making the 5GHz almost unusable.

Any tips on what kind of router would work best here?

Comment: Get a WiFi baby monitor

Comment: Did you try a different 2.4GHz WiFi channel?  There are eleven channels to choose from.  If the baby monitor interferes with all eleven channels, then maybe try another baby monitor (and complain to the original's manufacturer).

Comment: `5GHz works great when you're close to the router, but the range here in our old house is terrible` - Buy a wireless access point put it at the other end of your house, run a wire between the two APs.  If the building is too big, or you have too much interference, then adding another AP or two might be the best solution.

Comment: @saltcod: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Does the Netgear router have the same problem as the Actiontec one when running at 2.4GHz?

Comment: @James kinda yeah. In different parts of the house the wifi and the monitor interfere with each other at 2.3.  If I'm downloading something at max speed it will cause the monitor to loose connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here:

## 2.4GHz band:

The 2.4GHz band is used by many devices. It only has limited range so it is possible (heck: likely) that devices get in each others way. (e.g. Wireless at 2.4GHz, Bluetooth, microwaves, some mobile DECT phones, ...)

That does not mean that they have to jam each other. Just that they should not all be on the same precise frequency (What we commonly call 2.4GHz is actually cut into a dozen narrow bands. It is fine if one device is at one end of the bands (e.g. 2.4GHz channel 2) and one at the other end (e.g. 2.4GHz channel 13). If they use the same channel or a neighbouring channel you will get problems.

The simple solution to this might be to change the channel of your Wireless access point to a band which is not used. No new hardware is needed.

## 5GHz:

The 5GHz frequency can support higher bandwidth than the 2.4GHz devices. However the higher frequency also means is passes less well though walls, ceiling and other obstructions. 5GHz is nice is you are close to an access point. It is NOT a great solution to get reception in your whole house.

## Solutions:

1. First try if merely changing the channel in the 2.4GHz band will work.
2. Next try moving the 5GHz AP.
3. If neither works, look for other solutions such as wireless repeaters, allowing you to place multiple 5GHz points in the house.
4. If you have problems with a desktop, try wired network. It just works without hassle, has better performance and means you might be able to place the access points somewhere without worrying about reception near the desktop.

Comment: Interesting. Should the stock cheap Actiontec router work fine on a different channel?  Or should I still be looking at getting a different router?   Thanks!

Comment: First try to change the channel. If it does not work (e.g. because the baby monitor is badly designed and uses all channels) then you can always buy more hardware later. But often a channel change is all that is needed.

Comment: Hummm..... tried all the channels. No change. And I can't change the channel on the baby monitor. Next steps?

Comment: @saltcod: Try changing the router to 802.11n only (unless you need mixed mode)

Comment: Hummm even with n only on, on every channel the Netgear is much faster. Oh my! Maybe the stock Actiontec router is just not great?